# Data streaming fails with BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Data streaming fails with BigQuery

It took 1,000 daunting inserts at the streaming insert, and it suddenly failed today. Why do not you know why you failed?

In the log, "[1 row insertion failed]"

That's all.

Comment: Welcome to [so].Please check [ask] and [topics that can be asked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and also [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're doing streaming inserts in Go using the package [cloud.google.com/go/bigquery](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery).

The method [Inserter.Put()](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery#Inserter.Put) returns a [PutMultiError](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery#PutMultiError) when something goes wrong.  PutMultiError is responsible for [the message](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go/blob/c15541d6cecc1153b5cd2dbbb10371a796efe74c/bigquery/error.go#L82) you saw.  If you want to see more detail about the failure, you have to look at each sub-error separately.  Something like this:

```
err := uploader.Put(ctx, rows)
switch e := err.(type) {
case bigquery.PutMultiError:
    rowInsertionError := e[0]  // the first failed row
    for _, err := range rowInsertionError.Errors {
        log.Printf("err = %v", err)
    }
}
```